# Subtle smoke under light ( eevee )

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, volumetrics, eevee-render-engine

[image]
I know how to add volumetrically fog but I have no idea how to do this slow-moving smoke? that barely visible under light.

above image is a sample only.
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
I don't know if this is the right way to do it but I'm happy with the result.
[image]

1. Enable volumetric in Eevee.
2. Add lights.
3. Create a cube and scale/position it accordingly.
4. add material nodes to the cube.
5. Animate the texture using keyframes to move the smoke.

Comment: Good answer! You should probably add to the bullet points explicitly: "5. Animate, using keyframes, the number values highlighted in green"